# React Router v4 redirect to current page and the component disappears

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, material-ui

I am using react router to redirect to other pages. but when I redirect to the current page, the component handling the redirect disappears.

And this issue appears in another page, I don't want to compare the target path with current path to decide whether to redirect or to stay.
It's confusing, I have no idea why the LoggedMenu could disappear.

Could somebody help me with it?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import { List, ListItem, Avatar, Badge } from 'material-ui';
import { IconButton, IconMenu, MenuItem, FlatButton } from 'material-ui';

class LoggedMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirectTo: ''
    };
    this.redirectTo = this.redirectTo.bind(this);
  }

  redirectTo(pageName) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: pageName
    })
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.state.redirect) {
      case 'home':
        return <Redirect push to="/" />;
      case 'profile':
        return <Redirect push to="/profile" />;
      case 'settings':
        return <Redirect push to="/settings" />;
      case 'help':
        return <Redirect push to="/help" />;
      default:
        return (
          <IconMenu
            iconButtonElement={
              <IconButton style={{padding: 0}}>
                <MoreVertIcon color={white} />
              </IconButton>
            }
            anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
            targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
          >
            <MenuItem
              onClick={()=>{
                this.redirectTo('profile');
              }}
              primaryText="Profile"
            />
            <MenuItem
              onClick={()=>{
                this.redirectTo('settings');
              }}
              primaryText="Settings"
            />
            <MenuItem
              onClick={()=>{
                this.redirectTo('help');
              }}
              primaryText="Help"
            />
          </IconMenu>
        )
    }
  }
}
```

[how the LoggedMenu disappears after redirect to current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2cZZ.png)

Comment: ReactRouter v4 internally use shouldComponentUpdate...so need to make changes in props to rerender your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactRouter v4 internally use shouldComponentUpdate...so need to make changes in props to rerender your component.
 Try to wrap your component with withRouter or send updated props down to component otherwise it would not update

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(LoggedMenu))
```

Comment: perfect response. solved my problem. wrapping the redux component with *withRouter* injected the history so that I can navigate. The solution with <Redirect /> did not work out well for me because I was losing the redux state. Thanks!